# Pyinstaller: ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: python, windows, python-3.5, pyinstaller

I want to compile a .py file to a .exe file. I installed Pyinstaller (version 3.2.1) with entering `pip install pyinstaller` in the cmd. Then I changed directory to the desktop, which is the location where the file, that needs to be compiled, is located. The file is called "vierkantsvergelijking.py". I used `pyinstaller vierkantsvergelijking.py` to get the job done, but I ended up getting this error message: `ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application`.

The python version that I use is 3.5.0. Can someone please help? Thanks in advance!

Here is a screenshot of the error: [image]

Comment: You should install pypiwin32 as well as pyinstaller, from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pypiwin32/219